# Is there an equivalent to Python "struct.unpack_from" in Lua 5?

Tags: python, lua

I'm translating some Python code into Lua, and I got stuck on that line :

```py
cur_p = struct.unpack_from('I', data, block_3_offset_from)[0] + 0x10
```

So I was wondering what was the Lua 5 equivalent of Python struct.unpack_from.

Comment: Please provide a sample input and output

Comment: @Devesh Kumar Singh What do you mean? Sorry, I'm kinda new to coding.

Comment: I mean to say what would be the input to `struct.unpack_from` and what will it return?

Comment: According to the Python documentation :

struct.unpack_from(fmt, buffer[, offset=0])

Unpack the buffer according to the given format. The result is a tuple even if it contains exactly one item. The buffer must contain at least the amount of data required by the format (len(buffer[offset:]) must be at least calcsize(fmt)).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Comment: Why do you need `unpack_from` specifically? lua does have `string.unpack` which will take a `format` and a `string`. If your buffer is the hex value stored as a number then you can do some work to create a `unpack_from` in lua.